# Angular build failure

Tags: angular

There is an Angular project I'm working with, and recently I've changed my working environment. I installed Node, pulled the project from git, and now I'm getting error when trying to build my project with "ng build --prod":

```
ERROR in Error during template compile of 'AppModule'
Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'AnimateOnScrollModule' was called.
```

It's working fine on my old laptop with Windows 7 though. Currently I'm working on Windows 10.
AppModule:

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {ProductComponent} from './product/product.component';
import {HeaderComponent} from './header/header.component';
import {CalculateComponent} from './calculate/calculate.component';
import {FooterComponent} from './footer/footer.component';
import {TradeMainComponent} from './trade-main/trade-main.component';
import {CatalogComponent} from './catalog/catalog.component';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {ChooserComponent} from './chooser/chooser.component';
import {DragScrollModule} from 'ngx-drag-scroll';
import {OrderService} from './order.service';
import {AgmCoreModule} from '@agm/core';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import {InfoComponent} from './info/info.component';
import {MainComponent} from './main/main.component';
import { AdviceStepFirstComponent } from './advice-step-first/advice-step-first.component';
import { AdviceStepSecondComponent } from './advice-step-second/advice-step-second.component';
import {AnimateOnScrollModule} from 'ng2-animate-on-scroll';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', component: MainComponent, data: {page: 'main'}, children: [
            {path: '', component: ChooserComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
            {path: 'price-list', component: CatalogComponent, data: {page: 'price_list'}},
            {path: 'calculate', component: CalculateComponent, data: {page: 'calculate'}},
            {path: 'advice-step-first', component: AdviceStepFirstComponent, data: {page: 'advice-step-first'}},
            {path: 'advice-step-second', component: AdviceStepSecondComponent, data: {page: 'advice-step-second'}},
        ]
    },
    {path: 'price-list-main', component: CatalogComponent, data: {page: 'price_list'}},
    {path: 'calculate-main', component: CalculateComponent, data: {page: 'calculate'}},
];

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        ProductComponent,
        HeaderComponent,
        CalculateComponent, FooterComponent, TradeMainComponent, CatalogComponent, ChooserComponent, InfoComponent, MainComponent, AdviceStepFirstComponent, AdviceStepSecondComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
        DragScrollModule,
        AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
            apiKey: 'AIzaSyBVIv8aITm71woalbx6GFFMv1rI9lE6U5k'
        }),
        HttpClientModule,
        NgbModule.forRoot(),
        AnimateOnScrollModule.forRoot()
    ],
    providers: [OrderService],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Even if I remove AnimateOnScrollModule I'll get error on some other library/module. I just have no idea how to solve this. Is there any global solution for build app failures?

Comment: Side note about your question tag: Use [tag:angular] for angular 2+ and [tag:angularjs] for angular 1.x

Comment: `Is there any global solution for build app failures?` <= No. Read and analyze each error and then try to fix it based on the message call stack.

Answer (score 0):

Prior versions of the library does not compile on newer versions of angular compiler (5.x and newer). It seems that when changing your working environment the angular compiler version was updated but the library version is still the same.

Try deleting the node_modules folder and running npm install again.

If it didn't work, try adding the below to tsconfig.json (it's the workaround of the prior versions for newer angular compiler versions)

```
"include": [
    "src/**/*",
    "node_modules/ng2-animate-on-scroll/index.ts",
    "node_modules/ng2-animate-on-scroll/**/*.ts"
  ]
```

Comment: I've tryed your solutions, unfortunately they didnt help. It seems I'm gonna have to fix every error manually.